# Unhandled Promise rejection when trying to implement ngrx store-devtools

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngrx

I'm trying to user the dev-tools alongside the ngrx store. When I add them to the app.module I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Object(...) is not a function ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at new StoreDevtools (store-devtools.js:640)
```

The [current version of ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) is installed. This is the app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [...],
  providers: [...]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

These are my imports in the app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import {reducers} from "../store";
import {StoreDevtoolsModule} from "@ngrx/store-devtools";
import {StoreModule} from "@ngrx/store";
```

This is my reducer file:

```
import {ActionReducerMap} from '@ngrx/store';
import {Event} from "../models/event.model";
import {eventReducer} from "./reducer/event.reducer";


export interface State {
  events: Event[];
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  events: eventReducer
};
```

This is the event reducer (currently implements nothing):

```
import {Event} from "../../models/event.model";

export function eventReducer(state: Event[] = []): Event[] {
      return [];
  }
```

Current npm version: 6.4.1
Current ionic version: 4.3.0

Thanks for your help, appreciate it!

Comment: what are your import statements? also, show the content of the reducers file

Comment: @danday74 Edited

Comment: What is you angular Version?